# Nested Loop Ruby Answer

Tags: ruby, loops

Need assistance saving and totaling the "rainfall input" after the loop has ended. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
puts "How many years"
years_input = gets.to_i
for years_input in (1..years_input)
    puts "Years Passed: Years = " + years_input.to_s
for m in (1..12)
    puts "Month: Month # = " + m.to_s
    puts "Inches of rainfall"
    rainfall_input = gets.to_i
end
end
puts "Total Months"
puts (years_input * 12).to_s
puts "Total Rainfall"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a place to store your "counter" in this case the `total`:

```rb
puts "How many years"
years_input = gets.to_i
total_rainfall = 0

for years_input in (1..years_input)
  puts "Years Passed: Years = " + years_input.to_s
  for m in (1..12)
      puts "Month: Month # = " + m.to_s
      puts "Inches of rainfall"
      total_rainfall += gets.to_i
  end
end

puts "Total Months"
puts (years_input * 12).to_s

puts "Total Rainfall"
puts total_rainfall
```

Answer (score 1):

@Danilo has answered your question, so let me suggest how you might write your code in a more Ruby-like way. Let me first mention that `for` loops are *never* used by Ruby coders. Instead we use enumerators (like `each` and, here, `times` and `sum`) and blocks. That's in part to hide information within blocks to avoid it being seen by prying eyes outside the block.

```
require 'date'

puts "How many years?"
nbr_years = gets.to_i
puts "Number of years: #{nbr_years}"

nbr_years.times do
  puts "Which year?"
  y = gets.to_i
  tot = (1..12).sum do |m|
    puts "How many inches of rainfall in #{Date::MONTHNAMES[m]}, #{y}?"
    gets.to_f
  end
  puts "Total rainfall in #{y} was #{tot} inches"
end
```

`#{nbr_years}` in `"Number of years: #{nbr_years}"` converts `nbr_years` to a string by computing `nbr_years.to_s`. (See [Integer#to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-to_s)). It's called *string interpolation*. If `nbr_years` were an array, `Array#to_s` would be applied, and so on.

Search for "MONTHNAMES" in [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) and you will find that `Date::MONTHNAMES` (among several date-related constants) has been defined for your convenience:

```
Date::MONTHNAMES
  #=> [nil, "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  #    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

In pure Ruby we need `include 'date'` to access that constant (no need for that with Rails).

`nil` is just a placekeeper. `Date::MONTHNAMES[0]` is never referenced by coders.

Note that for inches of rainfall per month you want `gets.to_f` rather than `gets.to_i`.

We can simulate this code by replacing the `gets` statements with generated values.

```
y = 2015
puts "How many years?"
nbr_years = 2
puts "Number of years: #{nbr_years}"

nbr_years.times do
  puts
  puts "Which year?"
  y += 1
  tot = (1..12).sum do |m|
    puts "How many inches of rainfall in #{Date::MONTHNAMES[m]}, #{y}?"
    f = (10 * rand).round(2)
    puts "#{f} inches of rainfall in #{Date::MONTHNAMES[m]}, #{y}?"
    f 
  end
  puts "Total rainfall in #{y} was #{tot} inches"
end
```

The following (after minor editing) is displayed.

```
Which year?
How many inches of rainfall in January, 2016?
3.12 inches of rainfall in January, 2016?
How many inches of rainfall in February, 2016?
2.64 inches of rainfall in February, 2016?
...
How many inches of rainfall in December, 2016?
4.48 inches of rainfall in December, 2016?
Total rainfall in 2016 was 60.71 inches

Which year?
How many inches of rainfall in January, 2017?
7.15 inches of rainfall in January, 2017?
... 
How many inches of rainfall in December, 2017?
7.87 inches of rainfall in December, 2017?
Total rainfall in 2017 was 36.31 inches
```